# Database Driven Application

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, connection

I am currently in the design and trial step of a Java application to track targets at my work. I have created all GUIs, applied functionality for opening and closing windows and created a MySQL database with appropriate tables, including a Username and Password form which is connected and working with MySQL.

I have made 2 applications one for Operators(DB Input) the other for managers and display(DB Output).

my question is, using Netbeans can I submit user data (this will be the job serial) from the first app into MySQL and then recall results for display purposes in the second on an hour by hour basis?

I don't see why it isn't possible but I cannot find tutorials for this and do not want to waste time on trial and error to find out that it isn't possible.

Comment: In answer to your question yes it is possible - so you wont be wasting your time trying. As for doing it google _mysql java netbeans tutorial_ & see what comes up.

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very possible.

In order to `submit` user data, have that app connect to the database and use the SQL statements like `INSERT INTO table_name`. Also if you want users to have a login you can assign that in the connection. I recommend you look up how to use Prepared Statements. With this, you take in User Input and put it into the database.

In order to `recall` the results, you would also use SQL statements, but this time you select the whole table like `SELECT * table_name`. The * means select everything, however, you can specify the column. This would go into a variable to store your results (in JAVA its called a Result Set) and you would loop through the results to get each piece of data.

The `hour to hour` basis would just be a method or class that would execute the select statement with a timer.

If you are coding in Java, here's a decent tutorial:  http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_and_databases.html